# Antivirus warns about processes trying to access my webcam

Tags: malware, windows, antivirus

For the last two weeks I am constantly getting notifications from my antivirus about attempts  of using my webcam. I have always chosen "Block access", often after checking "remember for this aplication". But I am still getting these notificatiosn about every day. There are two diffrent notifications for two diffrent processes:

- C:Windows\System32\taskhostw.exe
- C:Windows\System32\DeviceConsensus.exe

What are these processes, and is it safe to allow access?

Here's the translation of the polish print screens below:

> **Attempt of getting access to webcam**
>     Signed Aplication
>
> Application (process of hosts of task of system Windows) tries to get access to your webcam.
>
> Application: ...
>      Company: ...
>      Reputation: discovered 3 months ago.
>
> Allow?
>       ...

[image: Screenshot of dialog #1 in polish.]

[image: Screenshot of dialog #2 in polish.]

Comment: taskhostw is part of the Windows Task Scheduler. Check your Scheduled tasks for anything running around that specific moment.

Answer (score 1):

DeviceConsensus.exe is part of a telemetry framework Windows 10 uses to report back on hardware errors. It probably wants to check that everything on your webcam is working right and as for taskhostw Nomad summarize it up very well in the comments.

PS: if you want it to stop asking just go to your privacy settings in Windows 10 then click camera after click Choose which apps can access your camera and uncheck "Feedback hub"